# Changed data frame row index, but old row index still appears above the column name of the new row index. How do I remove it?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have a dataframe which is created from input from a CSV file.

After processing it ends up looking something along the lines of this...

```
6  col1   col2   col3   col4
7  x1     x2     x3     x4
8  y1     y2     y3     y4
9  z1     z2     z3     z4
```

The numbers on the side are the row index which equals the row number in the CSV file itself. (Which is helpful as I need to flag errors in input and point out the cell reference)

col1 - col4 are the column names.

I want col1 to be the row index and use

```
df.set_index('col1', drop= True, inplace = True)
```

However, this results in something like the following

```
6      col2   col3   col4
col1   
x1     x2     x3     x4
y1     y2     y3     y4
z1     z2     z3     z4
```

I can reference the cells as I need to calling the column names using iloc, but the old row index for the column names in the top left corner is really bugging me.

Does anyone know how to remove this, so that the dataframe looks like one of the two below? I need to compare it with another dataframe for equality so I need them to be exactly the same.

```
       col2   col3   col4
col1   
x1     x2     x3     x4
y1     y2     y3     y4
z1     z2     z3     z4

col1   col2   col3   col4
x1     x2     x3     x4
y1     y2     y3     y4
z1     z2     z3     z4
```

Comment: try `df = df.rename_axis(None)` ? , then `set_index()`

Comment: Why not just x = x[:, 1:]?

Comment: because he wants set the index and rename  columns axis

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your columns have a name '6', use [`DataFrame.rename_axis`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.rename_axis.html):

```
df = df.rename_axis(columns = None).set_index('col1')
```